# Accessing xml using user's cookies

Tags: php, xml, cookies, curl

For a game-related project.

To access game data, the user has to "authorize" access. To do this, they visit a page on the site, which sets 3 cookies on the user's PC.

When the user then views certain XML URLs, the game server checks these cookies are correct, and returns the information required.

My question is, how do I parse these XML files using the user's cookies, to add styling to the data etc?

If I use cURL to load the URLs, and `CURLOPT_COOKIE` to pre-determine the relevant cookies, it returns the information correctly.

However, I will not know the user's cookies, as they are only valid for the game's domain.

I'm certain this is possible, although perhaps not through this method, as it has been done before using the same data.

The cookies set are:

```
toolbar_code = 19 digit auth code
toolbar_hash = 19 digit hashed username
toolbar_remember = true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't read XML cross-domain (without [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) anyway and that's not mature enough yet).

The simplest way to have a remote script that checks cookies and returns data to a caller site is to point a `<script>` to the remote site and have JavaScript execute in that, that gives the caller data. The normal way to do this is [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

Client-side:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function receiveData() {
        ...do something...
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://gamedataserver/getdata.php?jsonp=receiveData"></script>
```

Server-side:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
    if (...user auth is OK...) {
        $callbackfn= preg_replace('/[^a-z_]/', '', $_GET['jsonp']);
        $json= json_encode(...game data...);
        echo "$callbackfn($json);";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Some interesting points in there, but I have NO control over the game's site, so certainly couldn't execute a js there. Thanks for the ideas though. ALSO, "You can't read XML cross-domain" - When I used a cURL on the remote XML file, and provided valid cookies, the XML was returned?

Comment: Yes, that's simple client-server, not cross-domain. Cross-domain is when one site directs the user to make the request to a third party. Cross-domain access to an XML file is impossible (absent explicit methods from the target server to change that, like CORS and JSONP wrapping); it would be a gaping security hole otherwise. If the game site hasn't given you a third-party scripting interface to fetch the data, that's because they don't want third party sites reading their data.

Comment: Well, since there's even a ToS detailing how the data may be used / stored etc, I'd say they do, just via a confusing system. Thanks for your help anyway.